# what is the shortcut for "replace all" in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to hit a shortkey and replace all in Pycharm. 
After I hit ctrl+R, I key in text to search and text as replacement.
I need to click "Replace" / " Replace all".
I currently move my hand to mouse and click the button, but I do it many times in a day. Anyone knows what is the shortkey? Thanks.

Here's the official document shows how to find and replace by click the button
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Comment: ctrl+r by default (ctrl+shift+r for replace in all files)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, it actually depends on your `keymap` settings :)

Comment: It only highlights the target, not really replace it. @Joran Beasley

Comment: @lisa ... it is equivelent to clicking `edit>find>replace`

Comment: @Dekel Im pretty sure thats the *default* keybinding ... if you select a different scheme for your keymaps it could indeed not be that :P

Comment: @Joran Beasley yes, but you need to hit the button "replace" to make it effective. What is the shortcut for this?

Comment: enter `alt + the underlined letter of the operation` you wish to perform ... (look at the buttons ... replace is alt+p, replace all is alt+a) (or just press enter after typing the replacement ...)

Comment: Great!! This is the magic I'm looking for. Would you add this to your answer?@Joran Beasley

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> by default (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift+r</kbd> for replace in all files)

however if you  are using a different keymap it maybe different you can check under settings (under keymap>main menu> edit> find> replace)

[image]

after you type the replacement word you can press `enter` to perform the default action (replace this occurance... ) or you can press alt + the underlined letter on the button label (ie alt+a => replace all) to perform a different action ...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is quite simple: `Alt + a`

Replace All. PyCharm 2020.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

You can either select the word or move the cursor to the end of the word, and then the shortcut to replace all is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. Type the replacement, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the code and then press on `ctrl+g` multiple times to select all the occurrences. this way you will have multiple cursors blinking on the text.

so if you press "delete" everything will be deleted and multiple cursors still will be active.  you type whatever you want to replace it with and once you press "enter" everything will be replaced with the new text and multiple cursor will de deactive.